# How to measure the electrical properties to ensure the performance of a thin electrode/insulator stack-up?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, semiconductors, dielectric, conductors

I am a mechanical engineer by trade, and I am looking at some basic electrical properties that I need to measure to ensure the device meets the desired performance.
The device consists of a two-layer stack up consisting of a 100 nm electrode underneath a 500 nm dielectric layer. There are several electrodes that need to operate independently (so, they need to be isolated electrically from each other, and also not capacitively coupled due to close proximity), and the dielectric layer needs to withstand electric leakage/dielectric breakdown.

What would be the best ways to measure each of these?

Comment: To destruction on dielectric withstand voltage?

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question, Andy?

Comment: If you want to test the dielectric withstand voltage it might actually damage the material.

Comment: That's fine, I can afford to destructive testing (I have a lot of sample and can cut them into small pieces). I'm more looking at what characterization tools/equipment I need. I have an LCR meter and a 4 point probe, but not sure if these can be used to measure parasitic capacitance or leakage.